# Await for log file being idle for a period of time

Tags: bash, shell

Let say I have a `file.log` and some process put logs there while processing the data.
I want to wait for data to be processed.
How could I write simple script to wait for process to stop populate the log file for 3 minute for example?

Comment: Can you please give a clear example? What does `wait for process to stop populate the log file for 3 minute` mean?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to wait until such a time when the file's modification date is at least some set amount in the past.

With the usual Unix tools, we could use `find -mmin` to test if the file is old enough, and loop until it is:

```
while tmp=$(find -name filename -mmin +3) ; [ -z "$tmp" ] ; do 
    sleep 10
done
```

Assuming the `find` can ever match at most one file, the output will be empty if the file is too young, and the loop repeats.

On Linux, you could also use [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to get notified immediately when the file is closed, but that only works if there is only one process writing to it, and it doesn't close and re-open it while working.

Comment: no, precess will newer end, it could just become idle. Thanks for your answer, let me try it